# Excel User Defined Function issues with Excel Template

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working with a product based on Excel Document Level Customization. The project type is  “Excel 2013 Template” in Visual Studio.

Recently I have developed a User Defined Function which will be used to evaluate our own function. I have developed the User Defined Function based on the article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eric_carter/2004/12/01/writing-user-defined-functions-for-excel-in-net/

The User Defined Function works fine with the Excel Template of our product but it fails for one test case.

1. Open a new  Excel template of the product . [ex: Excel template 1]
2. Add the User Defined Function to a cell. [Evaluates the result successfully]
3. Open another Excel Template of the product. [ex: Excel template 2]
4. Add the User Defined Function to a cell. [Evaluates the result successfully]
5. Close the template opened in Step 1. [ie: Excel template 1)]
6. Add the User Defined Function to a cell of other template [ie: Excel template 2]

**Now I can notice the added function won’t get evaluated and End up with “#NAME?” error.**

I have checked the User Defined Function from the Excel’s Add-in list. It is active.
Any way I have re-installed the add-in programmatically in the workbook’s ActivateEvent, but no use.

**This problem will only occur if I close the template that was opened first.** 
Further this issue will not be there for saved work books.

When I debugged, I found one issue.
In our product we have our own set of commandbars added to the Excel’s context menu when our customization get opened.
The below sample code will add a command bar button in to the context menu of the cell.

```
 try
 {
    commandBars = (Office.CommandBars)Application.GetType().InvokeMember("CommandBars", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, Application, new object[] { });
    commandBarSheetMenu = commandBars["Cell"];                
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 commandBarButtonTest = (Office.CommandBarButton)commandBarSheetMenu.Controls.Add(1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 commandBarButtonTest.BeginGroup = true;
 commandBarButtonTest.Caption = "Test Me";
 commandBarButtonTest.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(commandBarButtonSheetCopy_Click);
```

When I remove/ comment the above code the User Defined Function start working even If I close the first opened template.

Is it a known problem with the Excel Template and User Defined Function when it is used with Command bars?

It would be great if someone can comment on the issue and suggest a solution to this issue.

Comment: Source files to re-create the issue is uploaded to https://1drv.ms/u/s!AKQQ5XmOgV6CgQE

Comment: Any one has an update to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate this issue even without command bars.
The same problem exists for the above test case, If I programmatically set the User Defined Function to any excel cell.

I have created two demo solutions that can be used to recreate the problem, by following the above test case.
These demo solutions are

1. Programmatically set the User Defined Function to a selected cell by pressing a button.
2. Workbook Template Customization with custom command bars

Y**ou can download the source files from** https://1drv.ms/u/s!AKQQ5XmOgV6CgQE

I have included the **Readme** files inside these Solutions separately with the instructions and steps to re-create the issue.

It would be great If some expert in this area can give me a solution to fix this problem